# Two ways to store the same data

Tags: database, database-design

At work we're creating a form to allow property agents to submit their new developments. A simplified version of our form is the following:

```
Bedrooms: [Enter a number]
Quantity: [Enter a number]

Add Another | Save
```

We allow agents to add multiple rows. However at the moment we have absolutely zero validation for duplicates, which in my opinion allows our database to store **identical data** in **two** ways:

```
| development_id | bedrooms | quantity |
|----------------|----------|----------|
| 1              | 3        | 1        |
| 1              | 3        | 1        |
| 1              | 3        | 3        |
```

Clearly a row could represent both **one** unit or a **group** of units.

I'm arguing that we should store the developments **either one way of the other**, but certainly not both. Unfortunately the back-end developers — I'm mostly front-end — are arguing that it's not a big deal, and to me that seems absurd.

For a simple example, by storing it as the above, a `COUNT` to obtain how many developments are for sale that have 3 bedrooms requires a `SELECT COUNT(*)` **and** consideration of the `quantity` field.

As a front-end developer it seems largely to be presentation logic, because transforming between rendering them as a list of single units, or grouping them together should be a front-end/API task, and the business logic should be one way or the other. Ultimately our table seems to be not normalised at all.

In my humble opinion there should be a unique index on `development_id, bedrooms`.

Am I right in my argument? Or horribly wrong?

**Edit:**

In clarification all of these are currently possible, all of which represent the same fact, and my argument is there should be only **one** way:

```
| development_id | bedrooms | quantity |
|----------------|----------|----------|
| 1              | 3        | 1        |
| 1              | 3        | 1        |
| 1              | 3        | 1        |
```

Same as:

```
| development_id | bedrooms | quantity |
|----------------|----------|----------|
| 1              | 3        | 1        |
| 1              | 3        | 2        |
```

Same as:

```
| development_id | bedrooms | quantity |
|----------------|----------|----------|
| 1              | 3        | 3        |
```

Comment: You're right, there should be only one way to record each fact in a database and duplicate rows should not be allowed. I'm not sure about your unique index though. What is development_id for, and what does it mean when you have multiple rows with the same value for it?

Comment: Well we also have a primary `id`, so it's more like: `id (pk) | development_id (fk) | bedrooms | phase | floor_area | price | quantity`, but the simple fact remains that there should not be duplicates - with a unique constraint on `development_id, bedrooms, phase, floor_area, price`.

Comment: "Clearly a row could represent both one unit or a group of units." Not clear to me, I don't understand. Nor the "two ways".

Comment: Sorry, scratch the word "both". I'll update my question to clarify the problem, essentially the database is able to record the same fact with different representations as @reaanb pointed out.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following... As I see it, the index should be on `development_id, bedrooms, quantity` because otherwise we're recording duplicates. It's okay for developers to add a second unit with different bedrooms.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Thanks. It's also worth mentioning that no other tables have a FK mapping to this table, so maybe that makes it clearer that the third option is the most logical?

Comment: If each row represents the quantity of units that have a certain number of bedrooms in a particular development, then a unique key on `development_id, bedrooms` makes sense to me. Don't include quantity in the key.

Comment: @reaanb Which table of the 4 are you talking about? What do you intend it to hold?

Comment: @philipxy I'm talking about adding a unique key to the original table to constrain it so that only the last example is valid.

Comment: @philipxy the last example makes the most sense to me. And sorry @reaanb I didn't mean to add `quantity` to the index.

Comment: Please address my comments, you're unclear. Is the 1st table an error? Does Edit section 2nd table hold any number of rows per development as long as each bedroom is accounted for in some row? (Headache to manipulate & constrain.) Units? Groups? You are not explaining. Guessing at your needs, best is the 3rd design "development DEVELOPMENT_ID has QUANTITY units with BEDROOMS bedrooms" UNIQUE/PK (development_id, bedrooms). PS Don't get you re FKs. FKs have nothing to do with meanings per se, ie update & query. They tell the DBMS when values for some columns appear as values for a UNIQUE/PK.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there should be only one way to record each fact in a database and duplicate rows should not be allowed. If each row represents the quantity of units that have a certain number of bedrooms in a particular development, then a unique key on `development_id, bedrooms` makes sense, and will prevent multiple entries for the same kind of unit in each development.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily, you & backend colleagues/rivals are both right.

It's not a big deal, for real (in the shown circumstances).
Although it really violates DB normalization (in the shown circumstances).

From what you reveal, there's no need to split into multiple rows. 
Although imagine it gains another attribute that distinct one three-bed from another, from now on. Say, apt plan. Or a timestamp, for whatever reason. 
It immediately starts making sense then.

Another thing here: reads are generally non-blocking, writes are.
That means, on a mature RDBMS with row-level locks, the inserts (and reads for COUNT) won't be competing, while updates to a counter would.

Although I'm way far from thinking your realty agents combined would ever achieve even single-digit TPS in their additions, so you may consider an issue non-existent for a scale. :-)